# Bass guitar amplifier

Tags: amplifiers, bass-guitar

I have a guitar amplifier at home and I am playing bass in a band. I am practicing at home and I wonder if I can use the guitar amplifier with the bass or will it damage the amp?

Comment: This question has already been answered here : http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3474/using-an-electric-bass-guitar-with-a-guitar-amp-hi-fi-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you play at a volume that doesn't start the speaker sounding distorted, it won't be problematic.I use an amp. with a 12" speaker in the studio, and while the sound is not good enough for stage work (you can hear but not 'feel' it), it's plenty good enough for practising. If it's a small speaker - 6" or 8", then you will have to keep the volume down to preserve the speaker. You could even use half decent headphones, after all, they produce the bass guitar on tracks you listen to, don't they ?

If you happen to like it really loud, then put the speaker closer to your ear ! H&S warning here...

Answer (score 0):

Guitars can be played through bass amps, but Bass guitars played through a guitar amp can damage it a lot if you crank it up too much.